# Не происходит запись в DB (javascript -> php)

Tags: php, javascript

Поле ставки:

```
<input type="text" name="u_stavka" size="3" value="10">
```

Кнопка которая рандомно генерирует числа:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 (. . . много кода . . .)

var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.onclick = function() {
      var resultL  = diceL.rollL();
      var resultR  = diceR.rollR();
      var status   = document.getElementById('status');

      if (parseInt(resultL) > parseInt(resultR)) {
          document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Выиграл";
         function dice_win(){
         ajax.exec({action : 'games.php', mode: 'dice_win', u_stavka: u_stavka, id: id});
          }
    }
      else if (parseInt(resultL) < parseInt(resultR)) {
         document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Проиграл";
         function dice_lose(){
         ajax.exec({action : 'games.php', mode: 'dice_lose', u_stavka: u_stavka, id: id});
    }
}
      else {
         document.getElementById("status").innerText = "НИЧЬЯ";
         }
         printNumber(resultL),printnumberR(resultR),status;
    };
</script>
```

в условие вписываю функции(`function dice_win()` и `function dice_lose()`) которая, должна зачислять/снимать количество очком указных в `input name="u_stavka"`

И сам файл файл games.php

```
$mode     = (string) $this->request['mode'];
$id       = (int) $this->request['id']; 
$points   = (int) $this->request['points']; 
$u_stavka = (string) @$this->request['u_stavka'];

switch($mode)
{       
    case 'dice_win':
$u_stavka    = (string) @$this->request['u_stavka'];
        DB()->query("UPDATE user SET points = $points + $u_stavka WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
    break;

    case 'dice_lose':
$u_stavka    = (string) @$this->request['u_stavka'];
        DB()->query("UPDATE user SET points = $points - $u_stavka WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
    break;
}
```

но списание/зачисление очков так и не происходит. Подскажите что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: вы бы библиотки/фреймворки на обоих сторонах указали что-ли.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pack.js"></script>` толку 0

Comment: ajax откуда например, или $this в php

Comment: всё это прописанно... есть по делу что?  `define('IN_PHP',   true);
define('SCRIPT', 'dice');
define('ROOT', './');
require(ROOT ."php.php");`

Comment: есть, в вопросе надо указать используемые библиотеки и фреймворки. ато я могу сказать у меня "код `this.render(cool)` не выводит танк на экран, чяднт ?"

Comment: а кстати, у вас sql injection :)

Comment: а ошибки есть какие-то?

Comment: Нет. Ошибок ни каких